# Division doesn't seem to work in Robotframework, what am I doing wrong?

Tags: python, robotframework

I am trying to do division using the `/` operator.
The resulting Floating point number is way off the mark.  What did I miss?

This is the output from RF:

```
KEYWORD: BuiltIn.Log ${nearTermsAmount}
Documentation:         

Logs the given message with the given level.
Start / End / Elapsed: 20190527 17:13:09.091 / 20190527 17:13:09.107 / 
17:13:09.107   INFO   3,666.00         
00:00:00.000 KEYWORD: BuiltIn.Log ${nearAllIn}
Documentation:         
 Logs the given message with the given level.
Start / End / Elapsed: 20190527 17:13:09.107 / 20190527 17:13:09.107 
17:13:09.107   INFO   1.607976        
00:00:00.015 KEYWORD: ${calNearTerms/BaseAmount} = BuiltIn.Run Keyword If      ${isBase}, Calculate Terms Amount, ${nearBaseAmount}, ${nearAllIn}, ELSE, Calculate Base Amount, ${nearTermsAmount}, ${nearAllIn}
Documentation:         

Runs the given keyword with the given arguments, if `condition` is true.
Start / End / Elapsed: 20190527 17:13:09.107 / 20190527 17:13:09.122 /   00:00:00.015
00:00:00.015 KEYWORD: rateTicketKeywords.Calculate Base Amount  ${nearTermsAmount}, ${nearAllIn}
Documentation:         

Calculates the base amount out of the given rate
Start / End / Elapsed: 20190527 17:13:09.107 / 20190527 17:13:09.122 / 00:00:00.015 
00:00:00.000 KEYWORD: ${baseAmount} = BuiltIn.Evaluate ${givenAmount} / ${givenRate}
00:00:00.015 KEYWORD: ${result} = rateTicketKeywords.Strip Numeric Commas ${baseAmount}
00:00:00.000 KEYWORD: ${result} = BuiltIn.Convert To Number ${result}, 5
17:13:09.122   INFO   ${calNearTerms/BaseAmount} = 3414.18529          
00:00:00.016 KEYWORD: ${otherAmount} = BuiltIn.Run Keyword If ${isBase}, Strip Numeric Commas, ${nearTermsAmount}, ELSE, Strip Numeric Commas, ${nearBaseAmount}
Documentation:         

Runs the given keyword with the given arguments, if `condition` is true.
Start / End / Elapsed: 20190527 17:13:09.122 / 20190527 17:13:09.138 / 00:00:00.016
00:00:00.016 KEYWORD: rateTicketKeywords.Strip Numeric Commas ${nearBaseAmount}
17:13:09.138   INFO   ${otherAmount} = 2279.88    
00:00:00.000 KEYWORD: ${diff} = BuiltIn.Evaluate ${calNearTerms/BaseAmount} - ${otherAmount}
00:00:00.000 KEYWORD: ${diff} = BuiltIn.Evaluate abs(${diff})
Documentation:         

Evaluates the given expression in Python and returns the results.
Start / End / Elapsed: 20190527 17:13:09.138 / 20190527 17:13:09.138 / 00:00:00.000
17:13:09.138   INFO   ${diff} = 1134.30529  
00:00:00.000 KEYWORD: ${diff} = BuiltIn.Evaluate ${diff} / ${otherAmount}
Documentation:         

Evaluates the given expression in Python and returns the results.
Start / End / Elapsed: 20190527 17:13:09.138 / 20190527 17:13:09.138 / 00:00:00.000
17:13:09.138   INFO   ${diff} = 0.497528505886      
00:00:00.000 KEYWORD: ${status} = BuiltIn.Evaluate ${diff} > 0.0006
00:00:00.015 KEYWORD: BuiltIn.Run Keyword If ${status}, FAIL, the   calculated near terms amount which was inserted in the trade ticked differ to  the near terms amount from the execution dialog, True
Documentation:         

Runs the given keyword with the given arguments, if `condition` is true.
Start / End / Elapsed: 20190527 17:13:09.138 / 20190527 17:13:09.153 / 00:00:00.015
00:00:00.015 KEYWORD: BuiltIn.Fail the calculated near terms amount which was inserted in the trade ticked differ to the near terms amount from the  execution dialog, True
Documentation:         

Fails the test with the given message and optionally alters its tags.



Source code:
Calculate Terms Amount
[Documentation]  Calculates the terms amount out of the given rate
[Arguments]  ${givenAmount}  ${givenRate}
log  ${givenAmount}
${givenAmount}=  Strip Numeric Commas  ${givenAmount}
#log  ${givenAmount}
${termsAmount}=  Evaluate  ${givenAmount} * ${givenRate}
${result}=  Strip Numeric Commas  ${termsAmount}
${result}=  Convert To Number  ${result}  5
[Return]  ${result}
```

The code tests the math done by the system being tested.  The number pulled from the application is correct, my answer is way off.

Comment: This log dump id quite hard to read and follow; in the future try to limit it to the problem at hand. You've included the source of "Calculate Terms Amount", but in the log it's visible that keyword is never ran - it's "Calculate Base Amount" that is executed; so the `Run Keyword If  ${isBase}` branches to it.

Comment: Hi Todor,  Thank you for pointing that out.  I have included the base amount method as well.  To summarize the log, givenAmount = 3,666.0.  The given rate is 1.60796.  Dividing the first by the second should return 2279.88.  Instead, the result is 3414.18529.  Why?  The code for Calc Base Amount is below:

Comment: Calculate Base Amount
  [Documentation]  Calculates the base amount out of the given rate
  [Arguments]  ${givenAmount}  ${givenRate}
  ${baseAmount}  Evaluate  ${givenAmount} / ${givenRate}
  ${result}=  Strip Numeric Commas  ${baseAmount}
  ${result}=  Convert To Number  ${result}  5
  [Return]  ${result}

Answer (score 0):

Division worked for me in a simple form

Code:

${Result}       Evaluate         ${Integer1}/${Integer2}

Answer (score -2):

When I cut and paste the Calculate Base Amount Keyword, I noticed the '=' symbol was missing (see below).  I am not sure what this would do but either it is syntactically correct, or the syntax checker could use some work :).

This line:

```
${baseAmount}  Evaluate  ${givenAmount} / ${givenRate}
```

Should be:

```
${baseAmount}=  Evaluate  ${givenAmount} / ${givenRate}
```

Comment: The `=` is optional, and doesn't provide any extra benefit.